# How to rename imported XML node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to rename the imported XML node name.
Below is my attempt where I create the new node name in XSL, but I end up in getting the XML node name as a child.

**My XML node:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<offices:sales
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:backend="http://www.example/1"
    xmlns:offices="http://www.example/2"
    xmlns:ix="http://www.example/3"
>
    <backend:YearlySales name="sales_2021" attribute_1="1">1000</backend:YearlySales>
</offices:sales>
```

**My XSL copy-of code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:backend="http://www.example/1"
    xmlns:offices="http://www.example/2"
    xmlns:ix="http://www.example/3"
>

    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      
      <html>
        <body>
          <ix:base>
          <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="offices:sales/backend:YearlySales">
        </xsl:copy-of>
          </ix:base>
        </body>      
      </html>
      
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**Result**

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "XSLT-compat">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:backend="http://www.example/1" xmlns:offices="http://www.example/2" xmlns:ix="http://www.example/3">
   <body>
      <ix:base>
         <backend:YearlySales name="sales_2021" attribute_1="1">1000</backend:YearlySales>
      </ix:base>
   </body>
</html>
```

**wanted result:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "XSLT-compat">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:backend="http://www.example/1" xmlns:offices="http://www.example/2" xmlns:ix="http://www.example/3">
   <body>
     <ix:base name="sales_2021" attribute_1="1">1 000</ix:base>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this produces what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:backend="http://www.example/1"
    xmlns:offices="http://www.example/2"
    xmlns:ix="http://www.example/3">

    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      
      <html>
        <body>
          <ix:base>
              <xsl:copy-of select="offices:sales/backend:YearlySales/@*"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="offices:sales/backend:YearlySales"/>
          </ix:base>
        </body>      
      </html>
      
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS6Q